# typescript says cwd does not existing on Process

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have a vuejs project in typescript and just now created a small nodejs typescript file.

The said ts file needs to read `process.cwd()` and `process.argv` but it complains at both.

It says either cwd or argv does not exist on process.

I have ts-node installed, tslib and @types/node

How is this resolved?

Comment: Could it be that the tsconfig for vue is configured for the browser and it therefore doesn't understand nodejs?

Comment: Is this project configured to run on a server or in the browser?

Comment: It is the stock tsconfig from vue clli - what would be a differentiating factor to be able to tell?